# HQL group by join field

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to group by a column retrieved with a `JOIN` statement.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, r.id 
FROM Allocation a 
JOIN a.person.roles r 
GROUP BY r.id
```

Unfortunately,  [Hql join and group by problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553677/hql-join-and-group-by-problem) thread did not help me as I am still getting a `SQLGrammarException`.

I am sure I have misunderstood something here, but I don't see what.
Could you help me understand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use GROUP BY you probably want to use aggregation function too. 
Have a look here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
>   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping

Besides that if you don't want to use aggregation function you should list all your parameters from SELECT in GROUP BY too.